# Sending JSON to Schematic Ipsum

Tags: ios, json

I'trying to get some random JSON from http://schematic-ipsum.herokuapp.com/ but I'm getting a response code 400.

Here is the code I'm using

```
+ (NSArray *)postData:(NSDictionary *)arguments toServer:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSArray *dataToReturn;

    // if urlString is nil, we default it to our server
    if(!urlString) urlString = JSON_SERVER;

    // of course we need to turn the string into a valid array
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    /* 
        prepare the post
    */

    // we need to catch possible errors
    NSError *error;

    // turn our arguments into NSData
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arguments options:0 error:&error];

    // we need the post' length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    // create the url request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    // here we'll check the server response
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

    // here's our data from the server
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
        // all good, let's see what we've got
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        // parse the response into a friendly format
        dataToReturn = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self returnJSONFromData:urlData]];
    } else {
        // somethin went wrong
        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
        // check if it's our fault
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Server error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    // return our formatted array or nil
    return dataToReturn;
}

+ (NSArray *)returnJSONFromData:(NSData *)urlData
{
    NSArray *dataToReturn;

    NSError *e = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: urlData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

    if (!jsonArray) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", [e localizedDescription]);
        dataToReturn = @[e];
    } else {
        dataToReturn = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:jsonArray];
        NSLog(@"data from json: %@", dataToReturn);
    }

    return dataToReturn;
}
```

and I'm calling it like this, using a demo JSON from their website:

```
NSDictionary *post = @{ @"type": @"object", @"properties": @{ @"id": @{ @"type": @"string", @"ipsum": @"id" }, @"name": @{ @"type": @"string", @"ipsum": @"name" }, @"email": @{ @"type": @"string", @"format": @"email" } }};
[RetrieveDataFromServer postData:post toServer:@"http://schematic-ipsum.herokuapp.com/"];
```

Comment: according to their page: Content-Type: application/json have you tried that?

Comment: I haven't and it works, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to respect the syntax of "Form Data" that the server takes. To obtain this, you can use Google Chrome "Inspect Element", choose "Network" tab then do a request and you'll see this:

[image]

Look at "Form Data" section and you'll find out your problem, it's because you didn't pass the right structure to server so that the server doesn't understand.
[image]

[image]

I took the defaults parameters of server which is:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "id"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "name"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "email"
    },
    "bio": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "sentence"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "avatar": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "small image"
    }
  }
}
```

So the data must be structured like this:

```
type:object
properties[id][type]:string
properties[id][ipsum]:id
properties[name][type]:string
properties[name][ipsum]:name
properties[email][type]:string
properties[email][format]:email
properties[bio][type]:string
properties[bio][ipsum]:sentence
properties[age][type]:integer
properties[avatar][type]:string
properties[avatar][ipsum]:small image
```

And don't forget to encode with percentage before sending it to server or you will fail again.
I tried to implement a method that take your dictionary and return the formatted form data, it works fine for this case but I'm not sure in a more general context. I'll post it here for you as a reference, it's really a mess, sorry for that but I don't have enough time for commenting.

```
- (NSString *)formatFormData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayPrefix = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *arrayResult = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self structureString:dictionary arrayPrefix:arrayPrefix arrayResult:arrayResult];
    return [arrayResult componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];;
}

- (void)structureString:(NSDictionary *)dictionay arrayPrefix:(NSMutableArray *)arrayPrefix arrayResult:(NSMutableArray *)arrayResult
{
    for(NSString *key in dictionay.allKeys)
    {
        NSObject *obj = [dictionay objectForKey:key];
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [arrayPrefix addObject:key];
            [self structureString:(NSDictionary *)obj arrayPrefix:arrayPrefix arrayResult:arrayResult];
        }
        else
        {
            NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayPrefix.count; i++)
            {
                NSString *eachPrefix = arrayPrefix[i];
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    [string appendString:eachPrefix];
                }
                else
                {
                    [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", eachPrefix]];
                }

            }
            if(arrayResult.count == 0)
            {
                [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, obj]];
            }
            else
            {
                [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]=%@", key, obj]];
            }

            [arrayResult addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
```

And in your current method, add these lines:

```
- (NSArray *)postData:(NSDictionary *)arguments toServer:(NSString *)urlString
{
    // omitted

    // turn our arguments into NSData
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arguments options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *stringTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    stringTemp = [self formatFormData:arguments];
    // encode form date before sending to server
    stringTemp = [stringTemp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    postData = [stringTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // omitted
}
```

Comment: Thanks for going through all the trouble of writing this. I had to try Matthew Clark's solution first, because it was easier to implement and it worked.